# Removing android-support-v4.jar effects

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I have two projects with the same dependencies (both without the android-support-v4.jar)

In the first one, I desperately want to try the `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light` that I removed the said library.

I was able to use `FragmentActivity` on that Project.

The next one, I did the same thing I did on the first project and I get a `Cannot Resolve symbol Fragment Activity`

My Question is, Why?

Comment: `FragmentActivity` comes with support-v4, you should always get that error when you remove the library

Comment: But on the other Project, I removed th support-v4 but I can still use the `FragmentActivity`

Comment: Probably means you didn't remove it. You have probably still something that depends on it. And since gradle adds dependencies of dependencies automatically you can have it added without mentioning it explicitly.